# Error in python code. Need to suggest what is missing

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing 

data_train = pd.read_csv("Train_data.csv")
data_test = pd.read_csv("Test_data.csv")

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

standardized_train_data = scaler.fit_transform(data_train.select_dtypes(include=['float64','int64']))
standardized_test_data = scaler.fit_transform(data_test.select_dtypes(include=['float64','int64']))
```

Upto here the code is working. After run the below commands, getting the error.

```
standardized_traindf = pd.DataFrame(sc_train, columns = cols)
standardized_testdf = pd.DataFrame(sc_test, columns = cols)

Error : name 'sc_train' is not defined
```

Where we have to defined those ones?

Comment: Should `sc_train` instead be `standardized_train_data`? And similarly `sc_test` should be `standardized_test_data`?

Comment: am I blind or is `sc_train` not defined?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. `sc_train` and `sc_test` are not defined. Those should probably be `standardized_train_data` and `standardized_test_data` respectively.